# How to restrict execution of a bash script to a specific user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm taking a basic operating systems class and have been given an assignment as follows:
*"Write a shell script that moves a file from the current folder to a sub-folder known as Backup. It should accept the source and destination as arguments to the script. The script should display an error if the user does not key in two arguments, or if the file was not found or if a different user (other than yourself) attempts to execute the script."*

I've written a script as follows:

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
 if ! [[ -f "$1" ]]; then
  echo Error: The file $1 was not found.
  exit 1
fi
else
  echo Error: Check syntax or number of arguments
  echo Correct use: $0 [source] [destination]
  exit 1
fi

echo Copying file $1 to $2/backup/$1
mkdir $2
mkdir $2/backup
cp $1 $2/backup
```

I've tested this on Cygwin on W7 since I don't have access to a linux environment at the moment (we usually SSH into a remote server but it's down for some reason) and it works for the first two requirements of checking the number of arguments passed and the file not found. I've done some searching but unfortunately I'm absolutely clueless as to how to do the last part that restricts the user execution - that's where I need help.

I'm much more interested in learning how it's done and why it's done that way as opposed to the code itself, so I would greatly appreciate extensive explanation if possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't take the time to indent your code properly, I will not take some time to understand what's going on/off.

Comment: You need to investigate the `id` command -- `man id`.

Comment: @sputnick I'm sorry I was having a bit of trouble indenting it for use here on StackOverFlow - not familiar with the tagging system.

Comment: click on the `?` above the editing box for markdown help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the environmental variable $USER to check against your own username

```
if [ "$USER" != "allowed_username" ]; then
  echo 'Access denied'
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: The `USER` variable can be overwritten easily by the invoking user, so it's not a good idea to use it for restricting access, e.g. try `USER=allowed_username ./script.sh`

Comment: @nif I'm not quite sure I understand. If possible, may you please explain further?

Comment: @WizaJ: any user can freely set their `$USER` environment variable, e.g. set the `USER` variable to `allowed_username` and execute the script, which will bypass the restriction.

Comment: @nif oh! You're right. I misunderstood you the first time but now I see what you mean. I suppose a more suitable approach to this would be the id command as suggested by @glennjackman?

Comment: @WizaJ: it's better but it's useless anyway if the script can be read by other users, they may simply copy it and remove the restriction. However, it would make sense if your script has [setuid or segid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) permissions set.

Comment: @nif then I suppose it'd be redundant for the purpose - which is simply to demonstrate some competency with the syntax in bash scripting - suffices for the assignment. However I think I'll raise it up with my  instructor and see their response. 

Thank you for pointing it out and explaining, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the obvious thing to do just to use file permissions? Make the script be owned by whichever user you want to be able to run it, and set the permissions to 0700.

If the script is supposed to figure out which user is running it, then use "id -u -n".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).